# How do I save the output of my java program in another file even if it contains commands like for, if etc?

Tags: java

In my code I have printed some patterns using for and if statements. I would like to ask how do I save the pattern that comes in the output in another text file so that I can access it later?
Here's my code

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class eqns
{
    double y,x,a,b,c;
    int u=0;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    void XYZ()throws IOException
    {
        String x1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"The eqn of a line is ax + by + c=0 Enter value of a","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        a=Double.parseDouble(x1);
         String y1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter value of b","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        b=Double.parseDouble(y1);
         String z1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter value of c","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        c=Double.parseDouble(z1);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The eqn of a line is "+a+"x + "+b+"y + "+c+"=0","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar COMFIRM",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
       System.out.println("                                                                              LINE: "+a+"X + "+b+"Y = "+c);
        System.out.println("                                                                          ---THE EQUATION OF A LINE IS ALWAYS A SINGLE DEGREE EQUATION---") ;
        for(y=20.0;y>=-20.0;y--)
        {
            for(x=-46.0;x<=46.0;x++)
            {

                if(a*x + b*y == c)
                {
                    u=u+1;
                    if(y==0&&x==0)
                        continue;

                    else if(x>0)
                        System.out.print("۞ ("+x+","+y+")");
                    else if(x==0 || y==0)
                    {
                      System.out.print("۞");
                      continue;
                    }
                        else
                    System.out.print("۞");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
                if(y==0)
                {

                        System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if(x==0)
                { 
                        System.out.print("*");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            System.out.println();
        }


        if(0==(((0)*a + c)/b))
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This line passes through the origin ","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if(u==0)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unfortunately this line is not satisfied by intger co-ordinates hence this line cannot be printed ","GRAPHS  ©RaghavGirgaonkar",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
           File f=new File("Output.txt");
           FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
           PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fos);
           pw.write(trial);
           pw.flush();
           fos.close();
           pw.close();
    }

    void main()throws IOException
    {
        eqns obj=new eqns();
        obj.XYZ();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: When you run the code pipe the output to an output file: `java eqns > output.txt`

Comment: Whether your program contains 'commands' like `if,` `for,` etc has no bearing on how you save output. Your question doesn't make sense.